# Restrict user to only edit its own items in zoo

Tags: component, user, zoo

I'm trying to restrict to each user to only edit its own items created in zoo but I can't achieve that.

My steps was:

1. Create user group `fake group` (inherit from public).
2. Create level access `fake level` and assign `fake group`
3. create user `fake-user` and assign `fake group` and `Administrator`
4. After that I logged in using `fake-user` and I created one zoo item.

I made tihs proccess with every user but when i get logged in, doesn't matter user, I am able to modify any item, in spite of I don create that item.

How could I solve this problem?

Note: I'm trying in `global configuration` > `permissions` > `Edit` -> `Denied` but no result.

Comment: It is possible it is caused by Administrator group added to the user. Administrator group users tend to have full permissions. If that is not the case you have to provide more informations cause not all of extensions our there provide a way to restrict permissions per object.

Answer (score 0):

There is some time since I last worked with zoo, but certainly zoo has its own local permissions which may override the global ones.

In addition, you should be specific with any permssions, in order these changes will reflect exactly what you want to do.

Having said that, note that any global permissions may affect many areas of the Joomla site. So for being specific with zoo only I would suggest to review your zoo app's local permissions.

So go:

> Zoo -> zoo app -> congig -> permissions tab.

And adjust accordingly.